# Dependency Injection in Unit of work with Autofac

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, autofac

Im going through a tutorial which uses EF 6 and a UnitOfWork pattern. The idea is to introduce Autofac and im not entirely sure how i should convert this line of code so it fits in with the project to introduce Dependency Injection

```
private readonly ContactsContext _context;

public UnitOfWork(ContactsContext context)
{
    _context = context;
    Customers = new CustomerRepository(_context);
}
   
public ICustomerRepository Customers { get; }
```

I can't change

```
Customers = new CustomerRepository(_context);
```

to

```
Customers = new ICustomerRepository(_context);
```

*Note the Interface as it throws an error*.

I can post the ICustomerRepository if required but I don't know how I should be handling the dependency in this case?

I can post more code if required but I didn't know if this is enough and I'm missing something simple or not?

Comment: An interface cant be instantiated.  Does `CustomerRepository` implement the interface `ICustomerRepository`?

Comment: @maccettura yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do this would be to take a constructor dependency on `ICustomerRepository` instead of instantiating a `CustomerRepository` yourself within the constructor:

```cs
private readonly ContactsContext _context;
public UnitOfWork(ContactsContext context, ICustomerRepository customerRepository)
{
     _context = context;
     Customers = customerRepository;
}
   
public ICustomerRepository Customers { get; }
```

Of course, you will also need to register `CustomerRepository` with Autofac as the implementation of `ICustomerRepository`.

```cs
builder.RegisterType<CustomerRepository>().As<ICustomerRepository>();
```

This means that you will be relying on Autofac to create the repository instead of doing so yourself (Autofac will 'know' to inject the `ContactsContext` into the constructor of `CustomerRepository`). That's the pervasive aspect of dependency injection - it ends up requiring you to adopt it [all the way down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down).

Comment: This way you will create another instance for `ContactsContext` if you did not register it as  'InstancePerLifetimeScope()' or other Singleton approaches.
Having multiple instances of DbContext is not what UnitOfWork is intending.